# Biblatex not working with ä ö ü and ß

Tags: biblatex, pdftex

I´m completely new to Latex. In the pdf in the main document, ä ö ü and ß works, but in the bibliography it is replaced with other characters.

I use pdfLaTeX to compile the files. And it worked before I added the .bbx files to format my bibliography. And I use biber and utf8 bibencoding

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,headsepline,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
    
    \usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{literatur.bib}
    
    \usepackage{palatino}  
    \usepackage{mathpazo}  
    
    \begin{document}
    Text
    \nocite{*}

    % Literaturverzeichnis
    \newpage
        \begin{sloppypar}
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
            \printbibliography[type=onlinemit,heading=subbibliography,
            title={Internet mit Author}]
        \end{sloppypar}
    \end{document}
```

bib-file:

```
@onlinemit{quelle,
autoren = {Jörg, Lühn},
titel = {Ärgerlich ß},
url = {https://www.google.com},
zuletztam = {04.10.22}
}
```

bbx-file:

```
\ProvidesFile{standard.bbx}

\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=verbatim]{autoren,zuletztam,url,titel}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{%
    autoren,zuletztam,url,titel}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{onlinemit}{%
    \printfield{autoren}%
    :
    \enquote{\printfield{titel}}%
    \space
    (Zuletzt aufgerufen am \printfield{zuletztam}).%
    \newline
    \printfield{url}
    \finentry}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you compile the bibliography with `biber`?

Comment: Yes, i use biber and also have enabled bibencoding=utf8 : 
 ```\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}```

Comment: Please do not link to Overleaf projects as a sole source of your problem description (Overleaf links may become stale, plus you may not want to share your complete work with all the world). Reduce your problem to a so-called minimal working example - a document that shows the issue with as little code as possible - and post it directly here in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the involved fields are declared as `verbatim` in the `.bbx` file. This means `biblatex` will try to read them byte-by-byte, which breaks down for UTF-8 characters (like `ß`, `ä`, `ö`) that are wider than a byte.

Unless you have a very good reason to, do not declare fields as `verbatim`. Most normal fields should be of `datatype=literal`. In the standard `biblatex` datamodel `verbatim` is used for special fields such as `doi`, `eprint` and `file`. Note that for URLs there is the special `datatype=uri`.

---

At least from the snippet I don't quite understand why you need the new entry type `@onlinemit` at all. All the fields you define are available in the standard `@online` type as well (granted, the field names are in English and not German, but that's about it).

Note also that the definition of the bibliography driver is fairly unidiomatic. It does not make use of `biblatex`'s punctuation buffer and field formats.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works now! You saved me so much research, never would I ever had the idea to check this.

I use onlinemit because I have different entry types for bibliography with an author and without and with different Headings. We can use it for our Document we have to write for school, and there is a strict formation of how the bibliography has to look like, with every comma and "". So I had to change the bibliography drivers, took me hours to do so 